# How to get a public url of a facebook ad?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We create facebook ads through facebooks graph api. That's working well.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative

Now we'd like to send our customer a link to the created ad. So the customer can view how his ad is looking. There is a preview endpoint, but this does not work for our customer, because his facebook user is not connected with our facebook app and never will be.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative

How can we "show" the final ad to our customer? Is there any way, even if our customer has no facebook account?

Answer (score -1):

First you need `effective_object_story_id` then you can redirect your customers to `https://fb.com/{effective_object_story_id}`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative/#Reading